# Помогите решить проблему с Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Изучаю Python и столкнулся с такой проблемой: При изучении библиотеки Selenium возникает ошибка:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Ниже прикладываю сам код.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

proxy_ip_port = '91.132.151.232:80'
proxy = Proxy()
proxy.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
proxy.http_proxy = proxy_ip_port
proxy.ssl_proxy = proxy_ip_port

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

s = Service("C:\\Users\\Антон\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\access\\chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get('https://2ip.ru/')

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: ну, не работает этот прокси-сервер, эка невидаль. возьмите следующий по списку.